# Frequency of water droplets from capillary

Tags: water, frequency, capillary-action

I would like to determine the drop formation frequency of water dripping from a capillary tube of some radius.

I know I can calculate the mass of each droplet by looking at the relations between the surface tension and mass of the drop.

But I cannot seem to find a way to calculate the frequency with which droplets will be formed.

I will use this to calculate the difference in formation frequency of water as a function of the water temperature.

-Jørgen

Comment: You'd want the mass flow rate through the capillary and then divide it by the critical mass of drop formation.